# Use only the sub categories from a category input

Tags: templating, categories, elementcriteriamodel

I have a category input. The category group has two levels.

[image]

When accessing the category input via Twig I am trying to only grab sub categories the user selected.  However when I use

```
{% set firstCat = entry.categoryInput.first %}
{% set cats = firstCat.getDescendants() %}
```

or `children` it grabs all the descendants from *Categories > Group* not just from the structure that was selected from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@carlcs helped me stumble upon a solution. Using the `.level(2)` method gave the desired result.

`{% set cats =  entry.categoryInput.level(2) %}`

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `level` parameter according to your requirements:

```
{% set cats = craft.categories({
    relatedTo: {
        sourceElement: entry,
        field: 'categoryInput'
    },
    level: 2,
    limit: null
}) %}
```

Comment: Will this work if the input is part of a matrix?

Comment: You would then need to set field to `myMatrixField.myCategoriesField`.

Comment: You pointed me in the correct direction.  Using level(2) off of the input works.

Comment: `entry.myCategoriesField` is actually just a shortcut for the full `craft.categories` criteria model I posted. So I'm surprised this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: This does work but I figured there should be a quicker way than calling `craft.categories`.  When you wrote "set the level" I thought I would try using `level(2)` off of the input which worked. As you said it is returning a criteria model, which confused me as to why using `getDescendants` or `children` didn't work.